# Get information from python file in html [web app using flask]

Tags: python, html, flask

So I am making a web app in Flask. In the `layout.html` file, there is a navbar on the top of the screen. It has 2 elements: `Create Family` and `Join Family`. I only want these to appear when a user a not created or joined a family.

I cannot even use the parameters of `render_template()` becuase the `layout.html` is not rendered anywhere in my `app.py` file

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd have in your app.py a route that returns the template:

```
return render_template('child.html', data=data)
```

child.html extends layout.html.
data contains everything your template needs.

In your template, you'll have an if

```
{% if data.show_create_join_family %}
```